# RPM creation not possible in 64 bit

Tags: unix, rpmbuild

I am trying to create a rpm in 64 bit as well as 32 bit, In 32 bit everything is fine. where as in 64 bit

```
[rpm] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
[rpm] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
[rpm] + /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
```

While executing the above lines it checks for unpackaged files and exits the rpm creation with a bad exit code

I observe in 64 bit a new folder getting created called `tmp` which has files in the following convention: `ABC.jar.jardir.dhYMgl9397`, I think while trying to copy these files it is exiting the process.

Please let me know the reason why RPM is failing. Is there any way to fix this other than adding the below lines in SPEC file?

```
%define __os_install_post %{nil}
%define __check_files %{nil}
```

By adding the above lines we can fix the issue, but I want to know the root cause of this issue.